# How do I return date incident assigned to specific group in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

how do i return a date in a report of when an incident (or item) was assigned to a specific group. not run yet, i need to return the create date of an incident and when it was assigned to the current assignment group.

I tried looking at the "Assignment Group" sub fields but cannot see and field relating to assignment date. the information is contained in the "Notes" section as a "Field Change" but cannot see where date for the change is held.

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-box Incident metric `Assignment Group` should give you the date/time that an Incident was assigned to a specific group. Look in the `metric_instance` table.

Comment: Hi: Thanks for the response. I tried looking for the metric_instance table but don't seem to be able to find it. I only get 2 items listed "Metric Category [asmt_metric_category]" and "Metric Result [asmt_metric_result]". Any idea why this is.